# Using Sphinx's `BuildDoc` on `setup.py`

Tags: python-sphinx, setuptools, setup.py

I am picking up a Python project that has the following in a `setup.py` script:

```
from sphinx.setup_command import BuildDoc

commands["build_sphinx"] = BuildDoc
cmd_opts["build_sphinx"] = {
    "project": ("setup.py", NAME),
    "version": ("setup.py", about["__version__"]),
    "release": ("setup.py", about["__version__"]),
    "source_dir": ("setup.py", "docs"),
}
```

And this is to pass to `setup()` from *setuptools*.
Now this gives me an import error, since it can't find the module.
From the *Sphinx* documentation we have:

```
# this is only necessary when not using setuptools/distribute
from sphinx.setup_command import BuildDoc
```

http://code.nabla.net/doc/sphinx/api/sphinx/setup_command/sphinx.setup_command.BuildDoc.html

So my question is if I can import this `BuildDoc` from somewhere, or should I just use *setuptools* in another way like suggested by the docs, and if so how do I do it?

I will also add *Poetry* in the project, so if there is a "*Poetry* with *Sphinx* thing", I might want that instead.

I tried looking for the `BuildDoc` import.

I now get that Sphinx integration with *setuptools* was deprecated in *Sphinx 7.0.0*, is there a way to integrate still?

Comment: I recommend you provide a [mre]. Your question as it is now is confusing to me. It does not show the commands and terminal output. -- You seem to be using a very old Sphinx documentation as reference. Do you really want to use that old version of Sphinx? -- What is it that you really want to achieve?

Comment: About the _Sphinx_ version I want to use the latest, which for now is 7.0.1.
The project I am updating is using setuptools . And and a custom command it adds the 'BuildDoc' function, that no longer exists in _Sphinx_.

Want I want to achieve now is a command line replacement for the 'BuildDoc' function, so I can add that to my makefile

Comment: I do no know what `BuildDoc` does or used to do. To build the documentation you can probably use [`sphinx-build`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html) in the *Makefile*. But really it is probably [documented prominently](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/quickstart.html#running-the-build), I have not checked the new versions of Sphinx and its documentation in a long while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BuildDoc` was a python counterpart of the command line sphinx-build.
I solved this by getting rid of the setuptools at all, and just add in the makefile:

```
poetry run sphinx-build
```

Just like [sinoroc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11138259/sinoroc) mentionend! Thanks